# Does print media queries `@media print` work on the iPad?

Tags: css, ipad, printing, media-queries

I have a web page that is using media queries to target print media.

Like this:

```
@media print {
    #user_profile h1 {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}
```

When I try to print the page from the iPad, via AirPrint, the print styles are not applied.

Is `@media print` not supported by mobile safari?

Answer (score 0):

If the other styles are without media query for screen, I think it will apply to print also.
Try adding to normal css a media query for screen,
Try to place all print css at the bottom to overwrite normal css.

Answer (score 0):

`@media print` is supported since iOS 1.0.

However, Mobile Safari does aggressive caching of assets and it's possible that your modified style sheet is not fetched from the server. You may append a query string (e.g. styles.css?v=1) to make sure the file is reloaded.